# In Frege's analysis of existence, is it assumed that a subject exists if it is predicable in the first-order?

Tags: existence

Frege holds that existence cannot be said to be a first-order predicate for the following reasons. If existence is to be considered to be a first-order predicate, it follows that in statements denying the existence of certain objects, the absurdity ensues of stating something along the following lines: there is an A such that A doesn't exist. The question is simply left to be asked, "how can there be an 'A' such that it doesn't exist?" This led Frege to believe that the 'A' which is being spoken about is itself only a concept, and existence is only a second-order predicate, as speaking of concepts rather than actual objects. This analysis thus is taken to defeat the traditional doctrine of the real distinction between essence and existence, which asserted that existence is said of objects.

But does Frege's anaylsis not assume that the objects in an existential context exist already? For example, Frege holds that there is a contradiction in saying 'there is an A such that A doesn't exist'. But this is only because Frege assumes that what is meant by 'there is an A' is existentially biased, so as to preemptively assert the actual existence of the object that's actual existence is the very thing in question. Could one instead hold that the object in question is itself existentially neutral? It could be argued that A being a concept or being actually existent is thus not evident in the *simple thought* of A itself, but rather determined in *complcated thoughts* about A, which is comprised of predicates therein, of which it seems existence must be said to a predicate to the object in question. The statement could thus be amended as follows: 'there is an A, such that A is existentially neutral, which in fact does not exist'. This would seem to avoid the criticism of Frege, so long as I understand Frege correctly.

Comment: I don't understand the sentence "But does Frege's anaylsis not assume that the objects in an existential context exist already? "

Comment: @virmaior I go on to explain what is meant by this later on. Frege seems to believe that an object that has a predicate of any kind, even in a context that is attempting to determine the existence of the said object, already exists, as is seen in his main criticism about the supposed contradiction in stating that an object fails to instantiate existence as a first-level predicate. The only reason this could be a contradiction is if Frege assumes that the objects already exist.

Comment: To me, the English doesn't really make sense there... I'm also a little confused by the format. Is the first paragraph your interpretation of Frege's project or from a source?

Comment: Regarding the second paragraph, I may not be understanding you correctly but when I read it I feel like you're misunderstanding *predication* for Frege. Predication is Xa. (a has property X). and thus it makes no sense to predicate of things that don't exist ...

Comment: For a modern "non-Fregean" view, see : Francesco Berto, [Existence as a Real Property : The Ontology of Meinongianism](https://books.google.it/books?id=UobUqRMyUawC&pg=PA1) (2013)

Comment: "There is an A such that A doesn't exist" is simply : **∃xAx ∧ ¬∃xAx** and thus is plainly contradictory; not only "according to Frege". We have no "logical" issues with sentences of form : **¬∃xAx**; the point of view of Frege is exactly : "exitsence" is **not** a predicate but a quantifier.

Comment: @virmaior I'm not sure what's confusing about the question. The first paragraph is standard reading of Frege. The second paragraph is a point that I'm making about Frege's analysis of predication, namely that it assumes existence of the object that's existence is the very thing being postulated of and about. As to how the property of existence is actually predicated and furthermore how nonexistence is predicated is not covered in the question (though the point made here would seem to require that 'nonexistence' is not a positively predicated property but rather the absence of a property).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I'm not sure you're catching the point of the question. McGinn makes a similar point that I just recently came across. Frege assumes a sense of existence that he does not explain, be it in the existence of concepts or the existence of the very objects that are said to be instances of some property. My point was to say that Frege clearly assumes a sense of existence of the object A in the statement 'there is some A' which he actually fails to explain. I then offered the idea that perhaps the means to solve such is to consider essences to actually be existentially neutral.

Comment: For Frege there exists : objects, concepts, functions, truth values (at least). Thus, what is a "not existing" object ? It is a not instantiated concept. What Frege denies, is that there "is" a sort of limbo where all "possible" objects lives, and the "real existsing" ones are those for which is right ro predicate "existence".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA The point is not about a possible 'limbo' of objects. The point is in what sense that which is assumed to exist actually exists, which Frege simply ignores. If existence is not predicated of an object, than it doesn't have to follow that the object exists in a sort of limbo. This is because the very statement 'there is some A' needn't be existentially informative. The predication of existence is the very thing that determines an object's existence, and it is according to such predication that the type of object that it is, be it real or conceptual, is determined.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are correct in what you say about Frege. In his logic, you can only quantify over things that exist, and all and only those things that exist have names. Therefore one cannot correctly predicate anything about things that do not exist.

Your idea about existentially neutral objects that may or may not exist sounds like the ontology of Meinong. He held that it was OK to speak of objects that subsist, because we can imagine them, and that existence is a first order property of such objects.